# Starting JavaFX from Main method of class which doesn't extend Application

Tags: inheritance, javafx, javafx-2

I'm having problem to start a JavaFX Application from a Main method of a class which doesn't extend `javafx.application.Application`

In my application there is the `MainApp.java` which should start the overriden method `start()` in the `MainUIController.java`, which extends `Applciation`

When I start the Main method from the `MainUIController.java` everything works fine.

**MainApp.java**

```
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonJDBCTemplate jdbc = connect();
        MainUIController mUIc = new MainUIController(jdbc);
        mUIc.start(new Stage());

    }

    public static PersonJDBCTemplate connect() {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "Beans.xml");
        PersonJDBCTemplate personJDBCTemplate = (PersonJDBCTemplate) context
                .getBean("personJDBCTemplate");
        return personJDBCTemplate;
    }
}
```

**MainUIController.java**

```
public class MainUIController extends Application {

    private Stage stage;
    // private User loggedUser;
    private final double MINIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH = 800.0;
    private final double MINIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 570.0;
    private String version = "0.6";
    private PersonJDBCTemplate jdbc;

    public MainUIController(PersonJDBCTemplate jdbc) {
        this.jdbc = jdbc;

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            stage = primaryStage;
            stage.setTitle("Sharp");
            stage.setMinWidth(MINIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH);
            stage.setMinHeight(MINIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
            stage.setResizable(false);
            gotoLogin();
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainUIController.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void gotoLogin() {
        try {
            LoginController login = (LoginController) replaceSceneContent("/fxml/Login.fxml");
            login.setApp(this);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainUIController.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**After running the *MainApp*, I get the following Error :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at javafx.stage.Window.<init>(Window.java:1110)
at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:236)
at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:224)
at ch.kit.sharp.main.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = main
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:445)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.setEventHandler(Screen.java:245)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.setScreenConfigurationListener(QuantumToolkit.java:600)
at javafx.stage.Screen.<clinit>(Screen.java:80)
... 4 more
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In addition to what Nejinx said, you must not directly call your `start()`, always call [`launch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String...%29), because it sets up the *JavaFX environment*, including `creation of stage` and `calls start()` passing the stage as an parameter to it.

[The docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#start%28javafx.stage.Stage%29) has a note specially stating this

> NOTE: This method is called on the JavaFX Application Thread

The [`launch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String...%29) can be called from *any class*, taking into consideration if the class is directly not extending [`javafx.application.Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html), then you must **pass the class extending it as an argument to the launch method.**

For example, consider you have a class `JavaFXMain` which extends `Application`

```
class JavaFXMain extends Application {...}
```

You can use any other class, to start the JavaFX Application.

```
class Main {
   ...
   public void someMethod() {
      ...
      JavaFXMain.launch(JavaFXMain.class); // Launch the JavaFX application
      ...
   }
}
```

In your case, you can try something like this inside the main method of `MainApp`:

```
// You may remove args if you don't intend to pass any arguments
MainUIController.launch(MainUIController.class, args)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialise the JavaFX environment, you cannot create a new Stage outside of launch(args); being called first on the class that extends Application.

Answer (score 0):

This was very helpful, but leaves the FX application as a stand alone application.  You cannot pass in objects from your non-FX code and you are provided with no handle to the Application instance that is created.

I came up with this workaround that I am not crazy about but it does allow parameters to be passed in.

```
package hacks;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Created by WorkDay on 8/11/16.<br>
 * <br>
 * HelloWorld is a javaFX app that needs parameters that are real objects
 */

class AppParameterLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld.launch(new ObjectThatContainsData("brave"), new ObjectThatContainsData("new"));
    }
}


public class HelloWorld extends Application {

    private static ObjectThatContainsData staticData1 = null;
    private static ObjectThatContainsData staticData2 = null;


    public static void launch(ObjectThatContainsData data1, ObjectThatContainsData data2) {
        HelloWorld.staticData1 = data1;
        HelloWorld.staticData2 = data2;
        Application.launch(HelloWorld.class);
    }

    private final ObjectThatContainsData data1 = HelloWorld.staticData1;
    private final ObjectThatContainsData data2 = HelloWorld.staticData2;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        String Text = "Hello "+data1+" "+data2+" World!";
        primaryStage.setTitle(Text);
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say '"+Text+"'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.setX(0);
        primaryStage.setY(0);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

class ObjectThatContainsData {
    public final String data;

    ObjectThatContainsData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data;
    }
}
```