# Javafx: Must the program start where the application are initiated?

Tags: java, javafx

So we have a calls, let's call it `GUI` that's gonna get the application running.

```
public class GUI extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        //GUI code
    }

    public void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to get a application to start without a main method if you want to start the program in another class?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062578/javafx-invoking-application-launchargs-from-a-method-other-than-main

Comment: Just wondering why you would want to do this. A more natural (to me) separation is to make the class that sets up the GUI a separate class (i.e. not an `Application` subclass) and let the `Application` subclass have a main method in the usual way. The `Application` subclass can just use the GUI class from its `start()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Off cause this is possible.
The only restriction is that the static method `launch()` is package private, so you must either place the other starting class in the same package or overwrite `launch()` so that it is public or provide a static public delegation method:

```
public class GUI extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
       //GUI code
    }

    // delegation not pssible with static methods
    // static public void launch(String[] args){

    static public void doLaunch(String[] args){
        launch(args);
     }
}

class StarterClass {

    public void main(String[] args){
       GUI.doLaunch(args);
    }
}
```

**[edit]** static methods cannot be overwritten.

Comment: The `doLaunch` method here is completely redundant. All you need is `Application.launch(GUI.class, args)` from your `StarterClass`