# Starting JavaFX from Main which doesn't extend Application (with arguments)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, game-engine

Please, take a look at this:

[Starting JavaFX from Main method of class which doesn't extend Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632356/starting-javafx-from-main-method-of-class-which-doesnt-extend-application)

Now that's easy. But **what if I want to start a class that extends Application, but that has arguments in its constructor?**

Why?

I am creating a simple silly game engine in JavaFX. Let's say I have a class that implements Application, something I call "EngineFX" for instance. This class defines a window and a canvas for drawing. [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) is used as cycle method. Whenever a cycle passes, the delta time and the Canvas graphics context are passed as arguments to a update.

The problem happens when this class is used by client classes. For example, in its constructor is passed a type called "Brain". This type has methods such as:

- init()
- stop()
- update(long deltaNanos , long deltaMilis , [GraphicsContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html) gc)

With the passage of "Brian" to the "EnfineFX" constructor, its methods are called at appropriate times (remember that "EngineFX" extends Application).

I can not do it. I'm unable to call for example (An exception is thrown):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Application.launch(EngineFX.class , args);
}
```

I need to instantiate and pass an argument to the EngineFX constructor. Is there any way to do this, or is there any other better approach? I researched the internet and can not find ways to accomplish this. Could somebody help me here please?

Comment: "The problem happens when this class is used by client classes. I need to instantiate and pass an argument to the EngineFX constructor (remember that "EngineFX" extends Application)." <== This design seems kind of broken, it breaks the [JavaFX application lifecycle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html).  I'm unclear on what you are trying to accomplish here, so I can't advise on how to fix the broken design.

Comment: Yes indeed. I really did not think much about the design here. With JavaFX I am having difficulties in this regard. Could you give me some tips or an better idea about it, please? I mean, is there a way to create a simple game engine in JavaFX, something to be extendible by client classes to implement the game logic? I'll have to search it on the internet... I thought it was simpler. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Designing a game engine is a bit too broad to really answer here.  As a broad pointer, your games can implement a [template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and your engine can implement Application and use a [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to invoke the appropriate template as required.  You can add new games to the classpath and discover them via reflection, and your engine can provide a menu of games to play.  My advice is, build two games first, then build a generic engine after...