# Reloading FXML after Locale change JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to add a functionality to my app which changes the language.

I wrote a following controller for this -> `https://pastebin.com/n3nXdAx8`

I'm having a problem with starting my JavaFx Application, when I run it I get a following error `https://hastebin.com/agakacubuv.js`

I tried to fix it following this topic [Starting JavaFX from Main method of class which doesn't extend Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632356/starting-javafx-from-main-method-of-class-which-doesnt-extend-application)
It's my Main class `https://pastebin.com/6s8iqcUe`

Comment: Please do not post links to code. Create a [MCVE] and post it, [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), directly in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
public static Stage stage=new Stage();
```

to

```
public static Stage stage;
```

You initialize the  `stage` in `start()` method anyway.

**Edit**

The second thing is that there is no such key as `bundles.main.view.application.title` (Main:32). try to use `main.view.application.title` instead.

Comment: Thanks it worked for my, but now start() throws Exception exc. When I change Exception to IOException I get this error https://hastebin.com/vuvuvelive.scala. How should I change the bundle?

Comment: please post your project tree and the bundle contents

Comment: I updated the answer, please see if it works for you